# Observing Missing Timestamp exception when doing creation via rest client

Tags: rest

When I invoke POST method to create the resource in a legacy(SOAP) backend. (Backe end is secured)in my API of a WUM updated WSO2 ESB 500 pack from a rest client, I'm observing exception as follows from the Backend soap service. The Other Methods (DELETE/GET) are working fine.

wsse:InvalidSecurity
Missing Timestamp

Could you please help to resolve this?